# Trying to map two properties together, getting error "LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToString()' method"

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq, automapper

I'm using AutoMapper to map the properties of two objects together, but I'm getting the error

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String
>   ToString()' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store
>   expression.

I don't really understand why, because I don't believe I'm trying to convert anything to a string.

**Here is my AutoMapper code:**

```
c.CreateMap<SerialNumber, SerialNumberModel>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Name, opts => opts.MapFrom(src => src.SerialNumberName.FirstOrDefault()));

c.CreateMap<Box, BoxedElectrodesRowModel>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.BoxId, opts => opts.MapFrom(src => src.BoxID))
    .ForMember(dest => dest.DateCreated, opts => opts.MapFrom(src => src.DateCreated))
    .ForMember(dest => dest.SerialNumbers, opts => opts.MapFrom(src => src.SerialNumbers));
```

Note: `SerialNumber` and `SerialNumberModel` are objects nested within `Box` and `BoxedElectrodesRowModel`, respectively.

The first block mapping the serial numbers together is the only part with strings, and each `Name` and `SerialNumberName` is already a string, so there should be no conversion happening.

The only other thing I can think of that may be causing issues is that in the last line of the second block I'm trying to map my `SerialNumbers` list (of `Name` strings) to the DB's `SerialNumbers` ICollection (of `SerialNumberName` strings). I tried to counteract this by changing my List to an ICollection so they would match, but I still got the error. I also tried added `.ToList()` to the last line, for the same reason, but that didn't work either.

**Edit:** Here are the classes:

**SerialNumber** (Auto-generated)

```
public partial class SerialNumber
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public SerialNumber()
    {
        this.Comments = new HashSet<Comment>();
        this.WIPHistories = new HashSet<WIPHistory>();
    }

    public int SerialNumberID { get; set; }
    public int IncomingLotID { get; set; }
    public string SerialNumberName { get; set; }
    public string LamPurchaseOrder { get; set; }
    public string LamLineNumber { get; set; }
    public bool Refurbished { get; set; }
    public int WIPLocationID { get; set; }
    public int StatusID { get; set; }
    public int RouteSectionStepID { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> RejectCategoryID { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> BoxID { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
    public virtual IncomingLot IncomingLot { get; set; }
    public virtual RejectCategory RejectCategory { get; set; }
    public virtual Status Status { get; set; }
    public virtual WIPLocation WIPLocation { get; set; }
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<WIPHistory> WIPHistories { get; set; }
    public virtual Box Box { get; set; }
    public virtual RouteSectionStep RouteSectionStep { get; set; }
}
```

**SerialNumberModel**

```
public class SerialNumberModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

**Box** (Auto-generated)

```
public partial class Box
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public Box()
    {
        this.SerialNumbers = new HashSet<SerialNumber>();
    }

    public int BoxID { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> DateShipped { get; set; }
    public string TrackingNumber { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> DateReceived { get; set; }
    public bool Active { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<SerialNumber> SerialNumbers { get; set; }
}
```

**BoxedElectrodesRowModel**

```
public class BoxedElectrodesRowModel
{
    public int BoxId { get; set; }
    public List<SerialNumberModel> SerialNumbers { get; set; } 
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> DateCreated { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I [answered](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41753827/getting-automapper-error-when-trying-to-map-nested-objects/41754183#41754183) your question yesterday. Did that not help? Plus why are you using `src.SerialNumberName.FirstOrDefault()`?

Comment: I don't know, because it lead to this new error. I don't know if this is a step forward or back. I can go accept it though, since at least I'm not getting the old error anymore.

Comment: Why are you doing the `FirstOrDefault()`? What error are you trying to solve?

Comment: Does your BoxedElectrodesRowModel class has the SerialNumberModel as an object (with the same name: SerialNumbers)? If that's the case then you don't even need the third line in second block as there is already a mapping defined for it.

Comment: `FirstOrDefault()` is there because without it, I get the error  "DbSortClause expressions must have a type that is order comparable."

Comment: If you want this to be responded accurately, you need to post your Models, 
SerialNumber, SerialNumberModel...

Comment: I removed the last line and I still get the error. Didn't seem to make anything worse though

Comment: @DavidEspino I added the classes

Answer (score 1):

Give it a go, I have added reverse mappings to. There is no need to manually tell automapper about the properties that have the same name.

```
c.CreateMap<SerialNumber, SerialNumberModel>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Name, opts => opts.MapFrom(src => src.SerialNumberName));
    c.CreateMap<SerialNumberModel, SerialNumber>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.SerialNumberName, opts => opts.MapFrom(src => src.Name));

c.CreateMap<Box, BoxedElectrodesRowModel>();
c.CreateMap<BoxedElectrodesRowModel, Box>();
```

Comment: I tried this but I get the same "LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToString()' method" error